# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException; need help understanding

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, target

What does this exception mean, and what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: PresentationFrameWork.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load

(System.xaml.xamlreader xamlreader,System.xaml.ixamlObjectWriterFactory 

WriterFactory,bool skipjournaledProperties,Object 

rootObject,System.xaml.xamlObjectWriterSettings Settings,System.uri baseuri) + 

0x164 bytes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From MSDN:

> The exception that is thrown by methods invoked through reflection. This class cannot be inherited.

**Try to see what the InnerException says** or take a look at the StackTrace to see what happens.

**EDIT:** Looking at your StackTrace it seems that occurs a problem while creating an element in your XAML. Check InnerException as said before to have more informations.

Comment: How can i check the inner exception?

Comment: To get more details on inner exception, you need the visual studio watch window. To open the Watch window, the debugger must be running or in break mode. From the Debug menu, choose Windows, then Watch, and click on Watch1, Watch2, Watch3, or Watch4.

In the "watch" window, type $exception and press enter. This provides a large amount of details on the components of the exception.

I have written an article on a recent experience with the targetinvocation error here 
http://denvycom.com/blog/debug-targentinvocationexception/