# Can't access repository to get object in visual studio MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In a controller I'm trying to get a "Grade", using:

```
 Grade g = gradeRepository.FindById(1);
```

The findById is declared in the GradeRepository:

```
public class GradeRepository : IGradeRepository
{
private ProjectContext context;
private DbSet<Grade> grades;

public GradeRepository(ProjectContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
    grades = context.Grades;
}

public IQueryable<Grade> FindAll()
{
    return grades.OrderBy(g => g.name);
}

public Grade FindById(int gradeId)
{
    return grades.Include(l => l.DeterminateTableProp).FirstOrDefault(g => g.GradeInt == gradeId);
}

public void Remove(Grade grade)
{
    grades.Remove(grade);
}

public void SaveChanges()
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}


}
```

The services are registered correctly in the nijectwebcommon file:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IContinentRepository>().To<ContinentRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IGradeRepository>().To<GradeRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ProjectContext>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        }
```

What could be the issue here?
I'm doing exactly the same as another repository I'm using.

Comment: What happens when you run `Grade g = gradeRepository.FindById(1);` in your code?

Comment: It throws an exception (which is catched and redirects to another page).

Comment: What is the exception type? Message?

Comment: SqlException.
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The target of the call has caused an exception.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550297/system-reflection-targetinvocationexception-whats-the-problem Then post a stack trace in your answer to show details of the `TargetInvocationException`.

Comment: Look at the InnerException!!!

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/x8b2qpd4j/ this?

Comment: I have resolved it, there were some more issues but the main one was that Grade didn't had a default ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

Inspect the [InnerException property of the TargetInvocationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find out what went wrong.

## The importance of the InnerException

Here is why you need to look at the `InnerException`. Some method, perhaps a factory method, was called through [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). That method threw an exception, and that exception got hidden away inside the `InnerException` property of `TargetInvocationException`, because that's what happens to reflection-invoked-method exceptions. They get hidden away. So, you need to inspect the `InnerException` to find out what *really* went wrong.

[The intro and remarks on MSDN tell the story](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `TargetInvocationException` quite well.

## What could be the issue here?

From looking at your code, it might be that reflection called the `GetConstructorForType` factory method, which will throw an exception if `Grade` lacks a default constructor.

```
internal static ConstructorInfo GetConstructorForType(Type type)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(type != null);
    ConstructorInfo ci = type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, System.Type.EmptyTypes, null);
        if (null == ci)
        {
            ThrowConstructorNoParameterless(type);
        }
    return ci;
}
```